# How to change PHP version in Bluehost access via SSH key?

Tags: php, ssh, hosting, putty, shared-hosting

i changed php version 5.4 to 5.6 in my BlueHost when i chek my info it is fine
[PHP VERSION LINK](http://www.prudentialhost.com/info.php)

but when i check via PUTTY i will get older version 5.2 i don't know why ?
i hace this two links but i don't know how to solve this ?
[LINK 1](https://box6114.bluehost.com:2083/cpsess8254409980/frontend/bluehost/cptt/phpconfig.html?post_login=71324776657589)
[LINK 2](https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/480)

Answer (score 0):

BlueHost has installed multiple php verions on the server and the default is 5.2, if you want to use 5.6 on command line, try to use **`/usr/php/56/etc/bin/php -v`** command to check the php version

Comment: How to use?? this im in **public_html** path

Comment: the path is incorrect it is /usr/php/56/bin/php -v without etc ;-)